# Token Based Authentication to Netsuite

Tags: rest, salesforce, netsuite

```
String nonce = String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomLong());
String tnow = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);
String baseString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&'+nonce+'&'+tnow+'';
system.debug('baseString'+ baseString);
String consumerSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc6c7691081bcb9b9eec6';
String tokenSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx91081bcb9b9eec6';
String signingkey = consumerSecret+'&'+tokenSecret;
system.debug('signingkey'+ signingkey);
Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HMAC-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(baseString), Blob.valueOf(signingkey));
String signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
system.debug('sig'+ sig);        
System.debug('Signature: '+signature);
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
String AuthString = 'OAuth realm="xxxxxxxx_SB1",oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxd68a2d175b93bf41be264c1fd",oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx439146c971fb0398c5db3f417", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_timestamp="'+tnow+'", oauth_nonce="'+nonce+'", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="'+signature+'"';
System.debug('Authorization: '+AuthString);
request.setEndpoint('https://xxxxxxxxxx-SB1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/956');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Accept','/');
request.setHeader('Authorization', AuthString);
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
request.setHeader('prefer', 'transient');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

The callout returns:

> "{" error ": {" code ":" INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT "," message ":" Invalid login attempt. "}} ".

Do you have any idea what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

The value signed in your `sig` is `baseString` ('ABCDE...') which means nothing to NetSuite.  The `input` parameter of your call to `Crypto.generateMac(String algorithmName, Blob input, Blob privateKey)` must consist of a URI encoded, concatenated string containing the HTTP request method, the base string URI, and the normalized request parameters.

See Constructing the Signature for Step One of the TBA Authorization Flow at https://{{accountid}}.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_157652390285.html